# mysql to sqoop - Connection Refused : java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, mysql, localhost, sqoop, hadoop2

I am trying to import data from mysql database on my localhost to HDFS using sqoop and whenever I try to run the code it is giving me connection refused exception.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop --username root --password 123@ajith --table mysql_sqoop --m 1

But it is showing the connection refused error.

Everything is installed in my local machine.

here is the error attached :

```html
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
16/05/04 14:44:50 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
16/05/04 14:44:50 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/05/04 14:44:50 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/05/04 14:44:50 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/05/04 14:44:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `mysql_sqoop` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/04 14:44:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `mysql_sqoop` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/04 14:44:51 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hduser_/compile/21bf2271e2878039d8e7c32486f8b7b7/mysql_sqoop.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/05/04 14:44:52 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hduser_/compile/21bf2271e2878039d8e7c32486f8b7b7/mysql_sqoop.jar
16/05/04 14:44:52 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
16/05/04 14:44:52 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
16/05/04 14:44:52 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
16/05/04 14:44:52 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
16/05/04 14:44:52 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of mysql_sqoop
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/05/04 14:44:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/05/04 14:44:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
16/05/04 14:44:53 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16/05/04 14:44:53 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/05/04 14:44:53 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ajith-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
 at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:145)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
 at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
 at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
 at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
 at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
 at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
 ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoop --username root --password 123@ajith --table mysql_sqoop --m 1
```

I suppose you should add the port 3306

Comment: I tried but the same error is happening again: please see the error  :                      ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ajith-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: Can you do this successfully?
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/
It should be the connection problem to the HDFS name node.
if not, use this parameter `--hadoop-home` to specify a explicit address.

Comment: When I did  hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/    : This is the error comming ->                          16/05/05 10:23:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Call From ajith-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: What is the right address for you to access the hdfs? you should use that address. Can you list the files in your hdfs like `hadoop fs -ls xxxx`

Comment: hadoop fs -ls /
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser_ supergroup          0 2016-05-03 15:44 /system
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser_ supergroup          0 2016-05-03 15:37 /user

Comment: check the hdfs config file 
like:

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop:8020</value>
</property>

Can you please use this value as sqoop parameter `--hadoop-home xxx` and try?

Comment: Some distribution of Hadoop use port 8020, others use 9000 to access HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking all the demons are running by using JPS command, connection refused error may come when demon services is not started.

To start all services start-all.sh (Note: It is deprecated but it will start all the services), if you want to start separate services then use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Pls restart Hadoop and try again.

./stop-dfs.sh

./stop-yarn.sh

./start-dfs.sh

./start-dfs.sh